# Horizontally align objects inside arrays of different equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

In this set of equations...

[image: image of tex output]

...is it possible, to horizontally align the columns with the `x`es?

More precisely, I would like to shift the right hand side of the upper equation, such that the `x`es are at the same horizontal position as the `x`es of the lower equation.

Here is the code:

### Code:

```
\begin{align}
 a &= b + \left(\begin{array}{cc} c & x \\ c & x \end{array}\right)\\
 d &= e + f + \left(\begin{array}{cc} ggg & x \\ ggg & x \end{array}\right)
\end{align}
```

Comment: I suppose you meant *vertically* align?

Comment: After thinking for a minute, I guess I am not sure about the correct use *horizontal* or *vertical alignment*, I mean to move objects *horizontally* to make them agree *vertically* :)

Comment: That's diagonally explained… :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `alignat` environment. By the way, there exists a `pmatrix` environment that makes typing shorter and cleaner:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
 a &= b &+ \begin{pmatrix}c & x \\ c & x \end{pmatrix} & \\
 d &= e & + f + \begin{pmatrix}ggg & x \\ ggg & x \end{pmatrix} &
 \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]